# Disassembling code with Hopper

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, decompilation, gdb, hopper

I'm trying to figure out what this code is doing. 
The first thing that I don't understand is the condition that tests if arg0's value is 0x2. I read that 0x2 in ASCII is STX (Start of text).
Here's the code.

```
void main(int arg0, int arg1) {
    var_30 = arg1;
    var_14 = 0x7a;
    var_10 = 0x0;
    if (LODWORD(arg0) == 0x2) goto loc_4006f3;

loc_4006df:
    rax = puts("Wrong");
    rax = exit(0x1);
    return;

loc_4006f3:
    LODWORD(rax) = 0x0;
    var_8 = sign_extend_32(LODWORD(time(0x0)));
    var_14 = 0x22334455;
    goto loc_40075c;

loc_40075c:
    if (var_14 > 0x10000000) goto loc_400711;

loc_400765:
    if (LODWORD(atoi(*(var_30 + 0x8))) == var_14) {
        rax = puts("Congratulations");
    }
    else {
        rax = puts("Wrong");
    }
    return;

loc_400711:
    var_14 = LODWORD(SeriousHash(LODWORD(var_14)));
    LODWORD(rax) = 0x0;
    rax = sleep(0x15180);
    LODWORD(rax) = 0x0;
    if (var_8 + 0x15180 <= sign_extend_32(LODWORD(time(0x0)))) goto loc_40075c;

loc_400752:
    rax = exit(0x2);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to read the actual disassembly rather than an attempted decompilation.

arg0 is really argc for the main function. So, it is comparing argc to 2 and exiting if it is not equal; i.e. there should be one argument passed to the executable (keep in mind there is always one implicit argument which is the executable name itself)